# Copying an IEnuemrable<T> - linq Select not functioning as expected

Tags: c#, linq

I was trying to copy an enumerable for the purposes of a comparison as assigning one enumerable to another just creates the reference an so the second will change as the first does. I had initally thought that using linq Select would create a second enumerable but was surprised to find that it to ends up just passing the reference.

The logic itself is used to determine if tag lists contain the same events for a particular display scenario and the code looks as below.

```
IEnumerable<Event> lastevents = null;
foreach (var tag in tags)
{
    IEnumerable<Event> thisevents = events.Where(e => e.Tags.Contains(tag));
    if (lastevents != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in thisevents)
        {
            if (!lastevents.Contains(item))
                return true;
        }
    }
    lastevents = thisevents.Select(e => e);
}
```

What would be the best way to copy the enumerable in this scenario?

Comment: Do you want to change the lists or the `Event` objects? Do you want to *copy* the references, or *clone* the objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way would be to call [`ToList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) or [`ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx). These both *materialize* the query. LINQ operators such as `Where` and `Select` are lazy where possible - they know about the original collection, and merely process the data as they're asked for it.

Of course, with the call to `ToList`/`ToArray`, you can remove the call to `Select`, as it's basically a no-op.

Answer (score 1):

Select won't copy the reference, it creates a new IEnumerable, but consuming the new one also consumes the original one. What you really want is to copy it to a list, so you can enumerate again.

thisevents.ToList()

Answer (score 1):

To copy a collection it has to exist as a collection first.

In the code that you showed, the `thisevents` object is not a collection, it's just an expression that is capable of creating the collection from it's source `events`. Each time you use the `thisevents` object it will create a new result by processing the data in `events`.

Using `Select` will create an expression that processes the source, and as the source in this case is an expression that processes `events`, the final result is still an expression that processes `events`. Using `Select` will just wrap the expression in another expression, it will not materialise the collection.

When you assign the expression to `lastevents` it will still be an expression that processes `events`, so if you change `events` the result of `lastevents` will also change as it's created on the fly.

You can use `ToList` or `ToArray` to materialise the result as an actual collection:

```
IEnumerable<Event> lastevents = null;
foreach (var tag in tags) {
  IEnumerable<Event> thisevents = events.Where(e => e.Tags.Contains(tag)).ToList();
  if (lastevents != null) {
    foreach (var item in thisevents) {
      if (!lastevents.Contains(item)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  lastevents = thisevents;
}
```

Note that as `thisevents` is an actual collection that is not dependent of `events` any more, it's not a problem to copy the reference into `lastevents`. You don't have to create another copy of the collection.